# Get geolocation data from jailbroken iphone shell script

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, geolocation, jailbreak

I finally jailbroke my iPhone 4S (iOS 5.1.1). I am very familiar with linux/windows programming (c/c++) and shell scripting.  I am not familiar with XCode/Objective-C and I don't have a mac.

I want a simple way to track my own geolocation and write the longitude/latitude (?accuracy?) to a text file on my iPhone every few minutes.  I don't need much accuracy.  The cell tower method should work fine so I don't kill my battery life.

If I can get a command line app that just spits out the lat/long then I believe I can figure out what needs to be done to turn it into a "background daemon" type app via some bash wrapper scripts.

I could not find an app in Cydia that did anything like this.  There were a few that auto-update your location on social websites but I *do not* want to do that.  I just want a local log so that I can scp it to my home server for my personal tracking. (I run a small business and sometimes need to prove to clients how long I was at their location)

Answer (score -1):

The [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html) documentation should answer any questions you have. But to get the current location of the phone:

```
// based on http://www.icodeblog.com/tag/corelocation/
@interface CFAAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

//Add a location manager property to this app delegate
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
@implementation CFAAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize locationManager=_locationManager;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if(self.locationManager==nil){
        _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        //I'm using ARC with this project so no need to release

        _locationManager.delegate=self;
        _locationManager.purpose = @"We will try to tell you where you are if you get lost";
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // other options exist, let's assume this one
        _locationManager.distanceFilter=500;
        self.locationManager=_locationManager;
    }

    return YES;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
   NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) &lt; 15.0)
    {
            //Location seems pretty accurate, let's use it!
            NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
                  newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                  newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
```

Reporting it to a datastore is an exercise left up to the reader.

Comment: He's going to deploy on a jailbroken device. Perhaps using python Cocoa-touch binding is more convenient, for a shell script.

Comment: It's a general solution, should work for non-jailbroken devices, like mine, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is basically asking for a way to do this without coding in Objective-C, so I doubt this helps him much.

Comment: I will look into the python coca-touch libraries.  Objective-C does not help (unless there is a shell that interprets it, but I doubt it).

Comment: FYI, OfflineMap is a good example on how to program with PyObjC and Cocoa Binding. http://code.google.com/p/iphoneofflinemap/